# constructor in class cannot be applied to given types android studio

Tags: java, android

i am making a recipe app and i m getting this error : constructor HomeItem in class HomeItem cannot be applied to given types;
        recipe.add(new HomeItem("viay",R.drawable.vietnamese));

This is my code:

> public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
>       View v;
>       private RecyclerView myrecyclerview;
>       private List recipe;
>       public HomeFragment() {
>       }
>
> ```
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
> ```
>
> v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
>
> return v;
>       }
>
> ```
> public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>     recipe = new ArrayList<>();
>     recipe.add(new HomeItem("viay",R.drawable.vietnamese));
> }
> ```

}

And here is HomeItem.java:

> public class HomeItem {
>
> ```
> private String RecipeName;
> private int RecipeImage;
>
> public HomeItem() {
>
> }
>
> public String getRecipeName() {
>     return RecipeName;
> }
>
> public int getRecipeImage() {
>     return RecipeImage;
> }
>
> public void setRecipeName(String recipeName) {
>     RecipeName = recipeName;
> }
>
> public void setRecipeImage(int recipeImage) {
>     RecipeImage = recipeImage;
> }
> ```
>
> }

What did i declared wrong in HomeItem? Thanks

Comment: Your HomeItem constructor has no parameters, but you're still feeding it arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass arguments to a constructor with no arguments.

Try this

```
public HomeItem(String recipieName, int recipieImage) {
    this.recipieName=recipieName;
    this.recipieImage=recipieImage;
}
```

p.s. use camel case for variables and feilds

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple coding problem. You define a constructor in `HomeItem` class without any parameters/arguments, but you try to instantiate HomeItem object and supplies some arguments to its constructor. You should use your `setters` method instead, or refactor your code to initialize all `HomeItem` class properties/fields in your constructor.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Well you are calling a `constructor` with parameters, but you only have an empty constructor, try this:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    recipe = new ArrayList<>();
    HomeItem item = new HomeItem();
    item.setRecipeName("viay");
    item.setRecipeImage(R.drawable.vietnamese);
    recipe.add(item);
}
```